# NodeJs How to wait 'require'?

Tags: node.js

I have many js tasks in separate files, each of them in the following format(It's hard to change these code):

```
!(async () => {
    time-consuming tasks
})()
```

Then in the main js:

```
exports.main_handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    require("XXX")
    require("XXX")
    require("XXX")
}
```

I think I have to follow the code structure in the main js. ('require' cost lower memory than child process)

The question is:
Is there a way to wait for the 'require' to make sure all tasks will be finished,just like:

```
exports.main_handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    await promise.all([require("XXX"),require("XXX")])
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what sort of code there is in `time-consuming tasks`

Comment: Do not use the format `!(async () => { time-consuming tasks })()` if you want something else to know when this is done.  The `async` function returns a promise that nobody is paying attention to so there's no way to know when it resolves and thus when the asynchronous stuff is done.  You need a function that someone can call that returns a promise that they can track.

Comment: FYI, in ESM modules only, you can use top level `await` which might be of some use here.  You don't show what your real code is in these "time consuming tasks" so it's hard for us to know what the best options are. Theoretical questions tend to get guesses as answers because you aren't fully describing what you're trying to do and not disclosing your real code.  We can always answer more completely if we can see the REAL code.

Comment: `require()` is synchronous.  It will not wait for asynchronous operations.  You can set `module.exports` to a promise and then have some calling code collect those promises and use `Promise.all()` on them.  That's a pretty strange design pattern.  If we could see the real code (both inside the modules and how you're attempting to use those modules), we could offer more educated ideas on the best design patterns to choose.